# ¿cómo pasar parámetros vacíos por url en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

He intentado pasar parámetros vacíos por URL al llamar a una función de un controlador de Codeifgniter, pero no me los detecta conrrectamente si alfuno de ellos está vacío. Ejemplo de función de controlador:

```
public function controlador_de_prueba($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)
{
                echo "el vador de param1 es _".$param1."_";
                echo "el vador de param1 es _".$param2."_";
                echo "el vador de param1 es _".$param3."_";
                echo "el vador de param1 es _".$param4."_";

}
```

Lo que ocurre es que es que si yo llamo por url pasando 4 parámetros (1, 2 ,3 y 4, por ejemplo) todo funciona ok:

"controlador_usuarios/controlador_de_prueba/1/2/3/4"

Pero si yo dejo uno de los parámetros vaciós ya me da error:

"controlador_usuarios/controlador_de_prueba/1///4"

---

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function controlador_usuarios::controlador_de_prueba(), 2 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\codigosqr7\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 4 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codigosqr7\application\controllers\controlador_usuarios.php

Line Number: 238

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codigosqr7\index.php
Line: 315

### Function: require_once

Comment: y porque no le cambia a otro valor si esta vacio y despues hace una comprabacion, ejemplo poner -1 o 0 en dado caso que no se use 0 para nada

Comment: prueba colocando los parámetros de la función en null, ,así si uno no llega el sistema no genera error: `$param1=null,$param2=null,$param3=null,$param4=null`

Comment: Muchas gracias, finalmente funcionó con vuestra ayuda.